Unity crashes once while loop is defined
I tried making a double jump mechanic to an already made snippet for player jump and move, but when I tried to make a while loop for detecting while the player is on the ground, it only crashes (It's more of a freeze than a crash)
Here is the code:
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController controller;
    private Vector3 playerVelocity;
    private bool groundedPlayer;
    private float playerSpeed = 2.0f;
    private float jumpHeight = 1.0f;
    private float gravityValue = -9.81f;

    int jumpValue = 1;

    private void Start()
    {
        controller = gameObject.AddComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Changes the height position of the player..
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            if (jumpValue < 2)
            {
                playerVelocity.y += Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -3.0f * gravityValue);
                jumpValue ++;
            }
            else
            {
                while (!groundedPlayer)
                {
                    if (groundedPlayer)
                    {
                        jumpValue = 0;
                    }
                } 
            }
        }

        if (groundedPlayer)
        {
            jumpValue = 0;
        }
        
        groundedPlayer = controller.isGrounded;
        if (groundedPlayer && playerVelocity.y < 0)
        {
            playerVelocity.y = 0f;
        }

        Vector3 move = new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);

        if (move != Vector3.zero)
        {
            gameObject.transform.forward = move;
        }

        playerVelocity.y += gravityValue * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(playerVelocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}

I have tried to make a thread for that, but it didn't work.
Edit: The problem with this script is:
                while (!groundedPlayer)
                {
                    if (groundedPlayer)
                    {
                        jumpValue = 0;
                    }
                }

It causes Unity to crash, that's the problem I'm trying to solve.

The while loop is infinite
Because the Update method runs every frame, it will run on a frame where the player is not grounded, and this is the same as while (true), since the player will never be grounded in this frame.
Just remove the while, the if inside it should be enough.

It looks like your loop is missing an exit condition which is why it's infinite.
Typically when writing a loop, you need to work in a mechanism to update the condition on which the loop is predicated so that the program can exit the loop.
Here's a simple example of a loop with an exit:
int count = 0;

// While loop to execute until count reaches 5
while (count < 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Count is: " + count);
    count++; // Increment count in each iteration
}

The loop condition is updated inside of the loop so that execution can exit correctly.

it does have an exit condition: 'groundedPlayer'

@SCOS100Alt it will never reach it because the player will never be grounded in the same frame it jumped
